# NextJS How to properly save sessions with products added to the cart

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am looking for a solution on how to properly hold products added to the cart in the session. Currently I solved it this way:

page.tsx

```
const ProductPage = () => {
  const { product, loading, error } = useProductData();
  const { cart, addToCart: addToCartHook } = useCartItems(); // Use the addToCart function from the hook

  const [isCartOpen, setIsCartOpen] = useState(false);

  // Assuming there is an interface for your product/item
interface ProductItem {
  databaseId: number;
  // Other properties...
}

const handleAddToCart = (item: ProductItem) => {
  // Use the addToCart function from the hook
  addToCartHook(item);

  // Add item to WooCommerce cart using GraphQL mutation
  addToCart(item.databaseId, 1); // Assuming quantity is 1, adjust as needed
};

  useEffect(() => {
    // Open the cart when the cart is updated
    if (cart.length > 0) {
      setIsCartOpen(true);
    }
  }, [cart]);

  const handleCloseCart = () => {
    setIsCartOpen(false);
  };

  return (
```

and here is hook useCartItems:

```
export const useCartItems = () => {
  
  // Load cart from localStorage on hook initialization
  const initialCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(initialCart);

  // Save cart to localStorage whenever it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }, [cart]);

  // Function to add an item to the cart
  const addToCart = (item) => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  // Function to clear the entire cart
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };

  // Function to remove a specific item from the cart
  const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
    const updatedCart = cart.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
    setCart(updatedCart);
  };

  // Calculate cart count
  const cartCount = cart.length;

  return {
    cart,
    cartCount,
    addToCart,
    clearCart,
    removeFromCart,
  };
};
```

This hook work and retrive items in cart, but the problem is with this part of function:
const initialCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];

This work but nextjs everytime return error:

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at useCartItems (./lib/woocommerce/index.ts:454:36)
    at Navbar (./components/layout/navbar/index.tsx:43:96)
  459 |
  460 |   // Load cart from localStorage on hook initialization
> 461 |   const initialCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
```

And I'm not sure if I should write it this way or maybe there is another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pages route and it first renders page on the server side and local storage is not accessible there, hence getting the error. You have make it conditional e.g use `useEffect` or other techniques, so it runs only when running on client side. So you can modify your hook this way to get the desired functionality:

**Solution one:**
using an extra useEffect

```
export const useCartItems = () => {

// Load cart from localStorage on hook initialization
   const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
    setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')))
  }, []);

 // Save cart to localStorage whenever it changes
 useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }, [cart]);

// Function to add an item to the cart
   const addToCart = (item) => {
   setCart([...cart, item]);
 };

 // Function to clear the entire cart
 const clearCart = () => {
   setCart([]);
  };

 // Function to remove a specific item from the cart
 const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
   const updatedCart = cart.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
   setCart(updatedCart);
 };

 // Calculate cart count
 const cartCount = cart.length;

  return {
   cart,
   cartCount,
   addToCart,
   clearCart,
   removeFromCart,
   };
  };
```

**Solution two**: Using same useEffect but setting on first render

```
export const useCartItems = () => {

// Load cart from localStorage on hook initialization
   const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
   const firstRender=useRef(true)


 // Save cart to localStorage whenever it changes
 useEffect(() => {
 if(firstRender.current){
    setCart(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')))
    fristRender.current=false;
  }else{
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));}
  }, [cart]);

// Function to add an item to the cart
   const addToCart = (item) => {
   setCart([...cart, item]);
 };

 // Function to clear the entire cart
 const clearCart = () => {
   setCart([]);
  };

 // Function to remove a specific item from the cart
 const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
   const updatedCart = cart.filter((item) => item.id !== itemId);
   setCart(updatedCart);
 };

 // Calculate cart count
 const cartCount = cart.length;

  return {
   cart,
   cartCount,
   addToCart,
   clearCart,
   removeFromCart,
   };
  };
```

Comment: thank you. I use first solution and working perfect.